# Не работают элементы в шапке

Tags: дефект

При нажатии на любой элемент в шапке сайта вместо появления выпадающего списка происходит переход на страницу. Неудобно. Тем более, для модераторских сообщений никакой страницы нет.

[image: шапка сайта]

Вот ошибки в консоли: про пиксель происходит при открытии страницы, про small - при клике.

[image: консоль браузера]

Comment: У меня вчера глючило-глючило, я тоже на мету чуть не написал, но потом перестало глючить

Comment: @andreymal, да, заработало.